# How to find volume of petrol in horizontal cylindrical tank?

Tags: math, volume, calculus, cylindrical

I have a task find out the amount of petrol in a horizontal cylindrical tank.
I have 3 parameters. I tried this formula but did't get, help me please

V=A*L

**radios=113.5,length=600,height=10** (height is level(cm) of petrol in Tank at end of the day)
A=Fluid Surface Area,  Side
A = r² × (π ⁄ 2 − arcsin(1−h ⁄ r)) − (r−h) ×√h×(2×r−h)

Regards
Murali

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use formula (18) from [Matworld page about circular segment](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html)

[image]

N.B. this is the same formula as yours, because Cos(Pi/2 - Alpha) = Sin(Alpha)

```
Volume := L * (R * R * Math.ArcCos((R - h)/ R) - (R - h) * Sqrt(2 * R * h - h * h))
```

Comment: I tried this formula also but i got wrong value A=πr^2-r^2 arccos[r-h/r]+(r-h)√(2rh-h^2)

Answer (score 0):

Volume of a cylinder is π *  r² * h
here in your case h = length.

so use this formula and try to find out.

for more info : http://www.mathopenref.com/cylindervolume.html

Comment: here i have horizontal tank,length=600,and i want volume(ltrs) of petrol at day End not volume of tank.